# VueJS Erros antes da API carregar

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Existe alguma forma de eu pedir para o *VueJS* esperar um pouco antes de tratar os erros do **DOM**?

Eu tenho por exemplo um `select` que recebe um `v-model` vindo da API, mas como o VueJS carrega o DOM primeiro antes da chamada `http`, ele já acusa erro no `select`

> type check failed for prop "options". Expected Array, got Undefined.

Esse erro está certo porque ele desenha o **DOM** sem nada no select, mas depois ele preenche com a minha chamada pra **API**. Tem como eu pedir para o VueJS esperar um pouco para eu trazer os dados da **API** e aí sim ele verifica o **DOM**?

Obrigado!!

*Obs: eu sei que inicializando a o parametro com array vazio funciona, mas queria uma outra maneira sem ser manual*

**@Edit**

**.Vue**

```
    <vue-select track-by="Value" v-model="data.nome" label="Name" :options="data.nomeList"></vue-select>

data(){
   data: {}
}
```

**.Js**

```
axios.get('url.com').then(response => {
     this.data= response.data;
})
```

Comment: Poste o codigo...

Comment: Há várias maneiras de controlar esse fluxo/logica antes de haver dados para mostrar ou render. Mostra os componentes onde tens o problema para percebermos melhor. Mas podias ter um `v-if="select.options"` no componente pai.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto não tem muito o que postar... mas de qualquer forma, coloquei ali um exemplo. 
@Sergio colocando um `v-if` pra verificar se o `v-model` estiver vazio é uma saída, mas ainda sim é muito manual... tem outra maneira? =/

Comment: No `data` esse `nomeList` devia ser `nomeList: []`. Como é que o tens lá?

Comment: Exatamente @Sergio, eu não tenho `nomeList` definido, e nem quero, porque é muito manual lembrar de todos parametros e inicializar um a um. Esse `array` já vem da API. Tem como fazer o Vue esperar a chamada `http` antes de apresentar o erro de **expects an array** no meu input?

Comment: Em Vue a maneira recomendada é definir isso no `data`. Podias fazer `:options="data.nomeList || []"` mas desaconselho pois acho útil definir o que é reactivo no `data` e assim ter informação de que propriedades são usadas pelo componente.

Comment: Entendi Sergio!! Obrigado :)